# change aspect ratio of TikZ-Feynman diagram

Tags: tikz-feynman

I have a tikz-feynman diagram that has a wide aspect ratio, and I'd like to change the aspect ratio to be more square.

cascade.txt:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\def\axisdefaultwidth{12cm}
\def\axisdefaultheight{9cm}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram [small, layered layout, vertical=a to b] {
  alpha -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma_o\)] a0,
  a0 -- [anti fermion, edge label=\(e^{+}\)] a1 ,
  a0 -- [fermion, edge label=\(e^{-}\)] a2 ,
  a1 -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\)] a3 ,
  a1 -- [anti fermion, edge label=\(e^{+}\)] a4 ,
  a2 -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\)] a5 ,
  a2 -- [fermion, edge label=\(e^{-}\)] a6 ,
  a3 -- [anti fermion, edge label=\(e^{+}\)] a7 ,
  a3 -- [fermion, edge label=\(e^{-}\)] a8 ,
  a4 -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\)] a9 ,
  a4 -- [anti fermion, edge label=\(e^{+}\)] a10 ,
  a5 -- [anti fermion, edge label=\(e^{+}\)] a11 ,
  a5 -- [fermion, edge label=\(e^{-}\)] a12 ,
  a6 -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\)] a13 ,
  a6 -- [fermion, edge label=\(e^{-}\)] a14 ,
  a7 -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\)] a15 ,
  a7 -- [anti fermion, edge label=\(e^{+}\)] a16 ,
  a8 -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\)] a17 ,
  a8 -- [fermion, edge label=\(e^{-}\)] a18 ,
  a9 -- [anti fermion, edge label=\(e^{+}\)] a19 ,
  a9 -- [fermion, edge label=\(e^{-}\)] a20 ,
  a10 -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\)] a21 ,
  a10 -- [anti fermion, edge label=\(e^{+}\)] a22 ,
  a11 -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\)] a23 ,
  a11 -- [anti fermion, edge label=\(e^{+}\)] a24 ,
  a12 -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\)] a25 ,
  a12 -- [fermion, edge label=\(e^{-}\)] a26 ,
  a13 -- [anti fermion, edge label=\(e^{+}\)] a27 ,
  a13 -- [fermion, edge label=\(e^{-}\)] a28 ,
  a14 -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\)] a29 ,
  a14 -- [fermion, edge label=\(e^{-}\)] a30 ,
};
\end{document}
```

Which is compiled via:

```
$ lualatex cascade.tex
```

Which renders to this: [cascade.pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEpsx.png) which has to be shrunk too much to fit on an A4 page.  I can force the width and height when I include it in my main document, but that also skews the text labels, making it look pretty bad.

How can I make the aspect ratio more square without distorting the text labels?

Comment: With `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}` your snippet does not compile on my machine, but with `\documentclass[tikz]{article}` it does.

Comment: One needs `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` as the very first instruction, with a recent TeX distribution.

Comment: @egreg Updated my answer, mille grazie!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the aspect ratio simply by adding `xscale` and `yscale`.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram [small, tree layout,xscale=0.5] {
  alpha[particle=\(\gamma_0\)] -- [photon] a0,
  a0 -- [anti fermion, edge label=\(e^{+}\)] a1 ,
  a0 -- [fermion, edge label=\(e^{-}\)] a2 ,
  a1 -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\)] a3 ,
  a1 -- [anti fermion, edge label=\(e^{+}\)] a4,
  a2 -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\)] a5,
  a2 -- [fermion, edge label=\(e^{-}\)] a6 ,
  a3 -- [anti fermion, edge label=\(e^{+}\)] a7 ,
  a3 -- [fermion, edge label=\(e^{-}\)] a8 ,
  a4 -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\)] a9 ,
  a4 -- [anti fermion, edge label=\(e^{+}\)] a10 ,
  a5 -- [anti fermion, edge label=\(e^{+}\)] a11 ,
  a5 -- [fermion, edge label=\(e^{-}\)] a12 ,
  a6 -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\)] a13 ,
  a6 -- [fermion, edge label=\(e^{-}\)] a14,
  a7 -- [photon] a15[particle=\(\gamma\)] ,
  a7 -- [anti fermion] a16[particle=\(e^{+}\)] ,
  a8 -- [photon] a17[particle=\(\gamma\)] ,
  a8 -- [fermion] a18[particle=\(e^{-}\)] ,
  a9 -- [anti fermion] a19[particle=\(e^{+}\)] ,
  a9 -- [fermion] a20[particle=\(e^{-}\)] ,
  a10 -- [photon] a21[particle=\(\gamma\)] ,
  a10 -- [anti fermion] a22[particle=\(\gamma\)] ,
  a11 -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\)] a23 ,
  a11 -- [anti fermion] a24[particle=\(e^{+}\)] ,
  a12 -- [photon] a25[particle=\(\gamma\)] ,
  a12 -- [fermion] a26[particle=\(e^{-}\)] ,
  a13 -- [anti fermion] a27[particle=\(e^{+}\)] ,
  a13 -- [fermion] a28[particle=\(e^{-}\)] ,
  a14 -- [photon] a29[particle=\(\gamma\)] ,
  a14 -- [fermion] a30[particle=\(e^{-}\)] ,
};
\end{document}
```

I also put the initial and final state particles away from the edges, which removes the overlapping labels. (BTW, your `vertical=a to b` had no effect because there are no nodes `a`, `b` in your diagram, so I dropped this.) **EDIT**: Changed the document class back to standalone, Mille grazie @egreg!

[image]